# Compare two symmetrically cont. distributed independent random variables X, Y which sharing the same median

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, random-variables

Let two independent random variables $X$ and $Y$ have the continuous distribution functions which are **symmetrical** with equal medians $\texttt{med}(X) = \texttt{med}(Y) = m$. Prove that

$$\Pr(X<Y) = \Pr(X>Y) = \tfrac{1}{2}$$

Some thoughts: without loss of generality, we assume $m=0$. Because it's continuous distributed, either $\ge,\le$ or $>,<$ does not matter. Now we have two independent, symmetrically distributed continuous random variables, which means for any $\delta$:

$\begin{eqnarray}
\Pr(X<-\delta) &= \Pr(X>\delta), \\
\Pr(X>-\delta) &= \Pr(X<\delta), \\
\Pr(X< \delta) + \Pr(X>\delta) &= 1, \\
\Pr(X<-\delta) + \Pr(X>-\delta) &= 1
\end{eqnarray}$

We also know $$\Pr(X<Y) + \Pr(X>Y) =1$$ and we only need to show $$\Pr(X<Y) = \Pr(X>Y)$$.

This approach seems stuck. If I took the integration approach described in this post [Probability that a Random Variable is less than or equal to another](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2496127/probability-that-a-random-variable-is-less-than-or-equal-to-another), I will end up with

$$\begin{align}
\Pr(X<Y) = E_Y[F_X(y)],\\
\Pr(Y<X) = E_X[F_Y(x)]
\end{align}$$

It would work if $X$ and $Y$ shared the same distribution functions. The condition specifies that $X$ and $Y$ do NOT share the same distribution necessarily. This direction also goes no further.

as This post [Does equal probability of rank imply two random variables symmetric around median?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3060743/does-equal-probability-of-rank-imply-two-random-variables-symmetric-around-media) pointed out that either **symmetric** or **identical** distributions for both $X$ and $Y$ are necessary for the claimed statement to be true.

Any insights are welcome, and appreciate any help in advance.

Answer (score 1):

$X$ being symmetric about $m$ means $m-(X-m)$ has the same distribution as $X$.
So,
$$P(X < Y) = P(m-(X-m) < m-(Y-m)) = \cdots$$

Comment: Thanks you for the prompt response, I see the trick is to reflect/mirror both random variables $X$ and $Y$ at the same time by utilizing the symmetry condition.  I will vote your answer up in the future, when I have enough reputation. Thanks again!